# How do I join 2 tables in SQL

Tags: php, sql, join, mysqli

```
$results = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM dayalpha WHERE d_id= '".$_POST['dtb']."'");

echo "<table border='0'>
<tr>
<td>Day Name</td>
<td>Type</td>
<td>Alphabet</td>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
 {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['dayname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['type'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['alpha'] ."</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['alpha1'] ."</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['alpha2'] ."</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['alpha3'] ."</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['alpha4'] ."</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['alpha5'] ."</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['alpha6'] ."</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

Here I display alphabets from my dayalpha table.  Every alphabet should be linked to multiple bnames from the babyname table wherever alpha == iname (i.e.. name initial
stored in the babyname table).

```
    -----------------
    My Babyname Table
    -----------------
    iname    bname    gender    mean

    K        Komal    Female    Tender
    K        Kiran    Male      Ray
    K        Kamlesh  Male      God
    N        Nityesh  Male      Yash

    -----------------
    My dayalpha table 
    -----------------
    dayname   type     alpha  alpha1  alpha2....
    Monday    vyainjan K      G       D
    Wednesday vyainjan T      D       N
```

How do I link a value from dayalpha to multiple values of babyname?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Are you designing this table from scratch?  Anytime you start typing var1, var2, var3, var4, you should recognize a pattern and that you could be doing it wrong.  If a dalalpha could have any number of alpha values, they should be in a separate table.

Comment: according to my code i get a output like this : Monday K G D

Comment: Now when i get this result i want the K to be hyperlinked which on click will give me list of bnames starting with K.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep the tables as is, then this SQL may work.

```
SELECT b.*
FROM babyname a
   INNER JOIN dayalpha b ON (a.iname = b.alpha OR a.iname = b.alpha2 OR a.iname = b.alpha3 ...)
WHERE b.dayname = 'Monday'
```

As I understand your question, this is the right answer.

Comment: Let me know if this helps or not.  If I answer your question, please accept and upvote.